# listening on multiple twisted endpoints

Tags: python, twisted

I have multiple server endpoints listening on different ports, using same protocol and factory

How do I know which one has made connection first?

```
endpoint1 = TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 8007)
endpoint.listen(QOTDFactory())
endpoint2 = TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 8008)
endpoint2.listen(QOTDFactory())
```

and so on....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way for you to tell the difference, since the objects you've constructed are exactly  the same.  If you wanted to tell the difference, consider something like:

```
endpoint1 = TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 8007)
endpoint.listen(QOTDFactory("tweedledee"))
endpoint2 = TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 8008)
endpoint2.listen(QOTDFactory("tweedledum"))
```

Then, in `QOTDFactory.buildProtocol`, you can easily print out whether your factory is `tweedledee` or `tweedledum`.

Comment: sorry im a little late to the party, suppose I pass a reactor into the listen function, will it try to connect immediately?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `IStreamServerEndpoint.listen` doesn't take a `reactor` argument.

Comment: nothing, i went through the tutorial on twistedmatrix I was thinking about reactor.run.